# Difference between SQLiteOpenHelper and SQLiteAssetHelper?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

What is the the difference between `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `SQLiteAssetHelper`?And how do I use them?

I know that when you use `SQLiteOpenHelper` you have to override the `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` methods. Furthermore one can add, remove, and look-up database values.

However, I read that `SQLiteAssetHelper` is better for something in my situation- being that I will have a pre-populated database and I will do more queries than adding or removing or anything else.

So basically:

1. What is the fundamental difference between these two?
2. Which one would be better for doing a query for data in the database that is not known at compile time but instead at runtime? (I will use `query()` or `SQLiteQueryBuilder()` for this.)
3. How would I go about setting up the right one?

Answer (score 7):

> 1) What is the fundamental difference between these two?

Both are helpers for managing and versioning database files. The difference is only in how the schema and initial contents are set up and how version migrations are done.

`SQLiteOpenHelper` sets up a new database file by calling your `onCreate()` callback and migrates old database files by calling your `onUpgrade()` callback.

`SQLiteAssetHelper` sets up a new database file by copying a file from your assets and migrates old database files by running upgrade scripts from assets.

> 2) Which one would be better for doing a query for data in the database that is not known at compile time but instead at runtime (will use query() or SQLiteQueryBuilder() right here)

Both will work just fine with dynamically inserted data and the code after obtaining a `SQLiteDatabase` object e.g. with `getWritableDatabase()` is the same.

> 3) And how would I go about setting up the right one?

- [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) for `SQLiteOpenHelper`
- [README](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/README.markdown) for `SQLiteAssetHelper`